# Chrome extension: Load a URL in existing tab via POST method

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, http-post

The Chrome extension method [chrome.tabs.update()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update) can load a new URL in an existing tab.

Also, the javascript method [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) can open a new tab and give that tab a name. Then that name can be used in a `<form>`'s target attribute like this `<form target="name" method=POST>`, so that the POST request is performed in the named tab.

I'm looking for a way to achieve the combination of these two things. That is, to open a URL via POST method in an existing tab.

I want to avoid doing any of these:

- Injecting javascript in the desired tab, because this requires additional permissions from the user
- Loading an intermediate/temporary extension page in the desired tab, because this would look ugly/disruptive/not clean to the user.

Is it possible to do such a thing?

Comment: @wOxxOm, unfortunately the script injection technique doesn't work on many cases, e.g. error pages, URLs starting with `chrome://`, forbidden URLs like the Chrome Web Store, blank pages, extension pages, app pages. It's too unreliable.

Comment: @wOxxOm, you suggested using script injection, and I replied saying why I can't use it, that's the point. About the "POST bit", replace the word "POST" with the word "GET", does it make sense to you in that case?

Comment: @wOxxOm, you suggested using `chrome.tabs.executeScript` to inject javascript in the first place. I just told you why I can't use it.